# Can state officials demand I-9s from a company?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, labor-law

I have a state official asking me copies of I-9 forms for my former employees.

Does a state official have the legal authority to demand federal documents such as I-9s from businesses in the state?

Comment: The answer to this is the answer to a more general question: does a state official have the legal authority to demand a document from a business? It depends on the official and the purpose.

Comment: Legal advice is off-topic here, but you can reword this to not include references to your case.  You'll also probably need to specify the jurisdiction more narrowly.